# Getting specific value from json file swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, instagram-api

I'm trying to get an instagram username, using their API, here's my code :

```
private func getUserInfo() {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=\(Settings.Access_Token)")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

The print statement returns the following so it works, but then I don't know how to access and store the username value and I don't understand others response to similar topics :

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "253876051",
    "username": "bruncheveuxcourtsyeuxverts",
    "profile_picture": "https:\/\/scontent.cdninstagram.com\/vp\/7eb0427fdd53a5b319d04c22af1c9f63\/5C977089\/t51.2885-19\/s150x150\/46724860_307687986508947_185550859294212096_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com",
    "full_name": "Lo\u00efc Buckwell",
    "bio": "Gogole de p\u00e8re en fils",
    "website": "",
    "is_business": false,
    "counts": {
      "media": 16,
      "follows": 106,
      "followed_by": 406
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jsonSerialization to convert the json object to swift dictionary object.

```
For example

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
guard let dataResponse = data,
          error == nil else {
          print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
          return }  
    do{ 
        //here dataResponse received from a network request 
        let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                               dataResponse, options: []) 
        print(jsonResponse) //Response result 
     } catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError) 
   }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Okay thanks ! It helps me a lot, but then how can I store the "username" value for exemple ?

Comment: let userName = jsonResponse["data"]["username"]

Comment: `let userName = ((foo as! [String: Any])["data"] as! [String: Any])["full_name"]!` It's rather ugly. A better option would be to use a parsing library like SwiftyJSON.

Comment: tried this one @LineeshKMohan, but I get an error "Type 'Any' has no subscript members"

Comment: Try the comment of Daniel. let userName = ((jsonResponse as! [String: Any])["data"] as! [String: Any])["username"] as! String

Comment: how to get json response for Facebook @LineeshKMohan

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the Codable system in Swift:

```
struct Counts: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case followedBy = "followed_by"
        case follows
        case media
    }
    let followedBy: Int
    let follows: Int
    let media: Int
}

struct InstagramUser: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bio
        case counts
        case fullName = "full_name"
        case id
        case isBusiness = "is_business"
        case profilePicture = "profile_picture"
        case username
        case website
    }

    let bio: String
    let counts: Counts
    let fullName: String
    let id: String
    let isBusiness: Bool
    let profilePicture: String
    let username: String
    let website: String
}

struct Meta: Codable {
    let code: Int
}

struct Output: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case user = "data"
        case meta
    }
    let user: InstagramUser
    let meta: Meta
}
```

Now inside your block you can use:

```
let ouptut = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Output.self, from: data)
let fullName = output.user.fullName
```

Comment: You may want to change `Data` to another name to avoid collision with the `Data` struct from Foundation

Comment: Can you extract _just_ the full name using Codable?

Comment: I prefer the first solution cause I don't understand this one that much but thanks anyway !

Comment: @Placard Don't waste your time with the other solution

Comment: @LeoDabus Which solution is better ?

Comment: IMHO, using SwiftyJSON is the best solution https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: @Placard use the Codable protocol aproach. Your code will be proper structured and much easier to manipulate